# Every matrix is congruent to a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I think I've read somewhere that any square matrix $M$ can be decomposed as $M=P^TDP$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Such statement looks very much like the spectral theorem, although in this case $P$ is not orthogonal in general (thus such fact, even if it is true, would be of little use). Does anyone know if my recollection is correct and, if so, a reference for that theorem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be true in general because $P^TDP$ is always symmetric and $M$ isn't necessarily.

Comment: However, the statement *does* hold for symmetric matrices.  This fact is sometimes referred to as [Sylvester's law of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) (in this context, we restrict $P$ to the invertible matrices).